# Classes and Data Abstraction

Tags: c++

Write a C++ class code to calculate the area of a rectangle as illustrated in the following  figure.
Your code must be in a Project contains 3 separate files.

- Implementation file (.cpp)
- Header file (.h)
- Main file (.cpp)

Here is the image for the question:

[image]

Code:

`main.cpp`:

```
   #include "area.h"
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {

       Rectangle obj;
       obj.setLength(8);
       obj.setWidth(3);
       cout<<"Area of Rectangle : "<<obj.getArea();
       cout<<endl;

       return 0;
   }
```

`area.h`:

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   #ifndef area_h
   #define area_h

  class Rectangle
  {
       public:
       double length, width,Area;
       Rectangle();     
       double setLength(int a );
       double setWidth(int b);
       double getArea();
  };
  #endif
```

---

`area.cpp`:

```
#include "area.h"

Rectangle::Rectangle()

double Rectangle::setLength(int a)
{length = a}
double Rectangle::setWidth(int b)
{width = b}

 double Rectangle::getArea(){return Area= a * b;}
```

When i run the code, it shows this error:

[image: ide screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your IDE works, but you need to either link in the object file for `area.cpp` when you're compiling `main.cpp`, or you need to compile both at the same time, eg. `g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp area.cpp`.

After you fix the linking issues, you need to change `getArea` to:

```
double Rectangle::getArea(){
    Area = length * width;
    return Area;
}
```

as `a` and `b` are both undefined.

Next, you have a bunch of syntax errors that should be corrected, such as missing semicolons.

Finally, both `setLength` and `setWidth` should be `void`, not `double` as they don't return anything.

Rewritten `area.cpp`:

```
#include "area.h"

void Rectangle::setLength(int a){
    length = a;
}
void Rectangle::setWidth(int b){
    width = b;
}

double Rectangle::getArea(){
    Area = length * width;
    return Area;
}
```

Other helpful links, though not directly related:

["std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n)

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: thank you very much for the help.i will try it now